# mysql performance - mysqltuner

Tags: mysql, performance, mysqltuner

On two database MySQL server (from two different websites), I launched a mysqltuner (we have a timeout on the web server, but we do not really know where it comes from at the moment)

Here are the optimizations to bring advise by mysqltuner, the databse runs on a machine with 4vcpu and 15 GB of ram (ubuntu 16.04 server).

#### mysqltuner recommendations:

**db01 PROD**

Variables to adjust:

```
query_cache_type (= 1)
join_buffer_size (> 256.0K, always use indexes with joins)
table_open_cache (> 431)
innodb_buffer_pool_size (> = 1G) if possible.
```

**db02 PROD:**

Variables to adjust:

```
max_connections (> 151)
wait_timeout (<28800)
interactive_timeout (<28800)
query_cache_type (= 1)
sort_buffer_size (> 256K)
read_rnd_buffer_size (> 256K)
join_buffer_size (> 256.0K, always use indexes with joins)
table_open_cache (> 431)
innodb_buffer_pool_size (> = 2G) if possible.
```

I want to hear your opinion and especially understand these parameters (I started working with MySQL a bit ^^).

Comment: Post the complete MySQLTuning report, please.

Comment: Please post complete results of  ubuntu  ulimit -a   so we can see your limits at the OS level   for both db01  and  db02.

Comment: Any chance you could post complete mysqltuner report OR ulimit -a results?  How about posting results (here or in pastebin.com) A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;  and B) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; ?  Thanks

Comment: Post in your Question (or on pastebin.com) the A) complete error log from the webserver with the timeout, B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;  C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; D) ulimit -a report E) complete mysqltuner report you have available for meaningful advice.

Answer (score 1):

High CPU --> find slow queries; deal with index(es) and/or formulation of queries.

High I/O --> Ditto.

High CPU or I/O and/or query timeouts --> Turn on the slowlog; that will catch it.  (Better to have `long_query_time = 1`.)

More data than RAM --> check `innodb_buffer_pool_size`

"Too many connections" --> various possible causes

None of the above?  --> Don't worry (yet).